# Retrieve data SQL database and display in Gridview on website in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created a website which replicates something like google. It is simply a search bar that allows customers to find out if we have the product they require.

1. The customer searches for product on website.
2. Query is sent to SQL
3. Results is displayed on website in a grid (could be multiple items)

I am currently using Visual Studios to build this. But I have no idea how to grab data from my database to create that connections and bring back some results.
I'm new to this and I apologise if this has been asked.

Comment: So far I have just created the Html - I don't know the best way to interact with SQL

Comment: What framework are you using for 1? javascript/angularjs or something else?

Comment: i'm really new to this all - all I have is literally html and css - nothing else.

Comment: @cocojay ,this question in my terms has a broad scope as there are many ways(maybe too many) to implement the required functionality.However including relevant code in specific programming paradigm/framework will likely to help community members to guide/identify problem you are facing.

Comment: i d suggest first you get hold on this topic : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/637430/Angular-js-example-application
come back here when you are done, then we can talk about on how to get the SQL working.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to take would be to implement a SQL connection when a button is clicked or whatever your requirement is [Sql guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" + 
                                   "password=password;server=serverurl;" + 
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
                                   "database=database; " + 
                                   "connection timeout=30");
```

Add a Gridview to your page in required position, and set the datasource as the result from your datareader [tutorial here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14249/How-to-populate-DataGridView-GridView-with-SQL-sta)

```
string strSQLconnection = "Data Source=dbServer;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table1", sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If you want to know more, try beeing more specific with your question